# Wrong CSS and JS paths after moving wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

i moved my wordpress website from domain-a.com to domain-b.com and changed the the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL with define and the siteurl and home with update_option. I can access the page now but the css and js-files still links to the domain-a.com. What else can i do?
regards

Comment: Do you have a URL we can look at? js and css files aren't normally effected with a domain change unless the directory is different. Check using dev tools the directory your js & css files are located

Comment: Are your CSS/JS file links hard coded? This may be a cache issue. If not, you can run a `find-replace` on your database. WP Migrate DB is a good plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to codex [Moving WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/#changing-your-domain-name-and-urls). Your database may have records that still refer to domain-a.com. There are several options listed for search/replacing safely. I usually use [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/). If you can't access the dashboard, you'll need to use a [PHP script to update the database](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Hopefully you have backups in case things get really wonky!

You may also consider reviewing any theme or plugin files that you have customized (if you're using a child theme or have written a plugin yourself) to ensure that there are no hardcoded domains.